# Setting content to another layout(inflater)

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to set an image to to another layout by using inflater. I'm messing it up somehow, but not sure where. The targeted layout is info_window.

```
    View v= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
            ImageView img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageVVV);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.list);
            LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearkata);
            rl.addView(v);
```

Comment: You are retrieving `rl` from `v` and then adding `v` to `rl`: inception.

Comment: Soo LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearkata); ? That throws a null object reference

Comment: rl(LinearLayout) in v(View) and you add v to rl

Comment: Rasoul Miri can you write it a bit better, I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Every layout should have width height to be specified along with layout parameters. and in LinearLayout orientation also need to be set.. And yeah view is a root.. and within view layout inserted that is your linear layout.. so you are doing within layout inserting layout which leads to crash.

```
 LinearLayout llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMain);
 ImageView ivMyImage= new ImageView(this);
 ivMyImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image_name);
 llMain.addView(ivMyImage);
```

Try this out.. :) and go to this documents will help you to understand this better.

[ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

[View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

[Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: I'm getting a new error with your code  - java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Do you have any other layout in your info_window layout??

Comment: Yeah, one nested in the other, id of parent is linearkata. By (YourActivity.this); do you mean the current activity?

Comment: Yes.. YourAcivity name . and do you want to add new nested linear layout within your parent layout or just want to add imageview within the layout ..??

Comment: Just add imageview within the layout.

Comment: ImageView ivMyImage= new ImageView(this); Not able to do "this". So instead I put   ImageView ivMyImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageVVV); and get a null object reference..

Comment: Yeah obviously dear you'll get null object reference.. findViewById is for referring to already mentioned views within the layout. while you want to add a new one.. so it won't work.. do one thing write your code.. would be more easy to help you.

Comment: And you are doing this within activity or within fragment?

Comment: Listen, I care not if I'm going to create a new imageview or use existing, but I cannot create one because -> ImageView cannot be applied in GetHttpResponse.

Comment: It is a FragmentActivity

Comment: I'm trying to do this inside an AsyncTask if that makes it any clearer private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

Comment: 1) for 'this' you have to use getActivity(), if it is a fragment

Comment: 2) i am not able to understand that what exactly you are trying to achieve over here.. :) why you want to use GetHttpResponse?

Comment: The method gets data from a database such as strings and images which I'm trying to populate into a google Map. I have a infoContentWindow for the markers which is the info_window. Can you eloborate how to use "getActivity()" ?

Comment: Try this    ImageView ivMyImage= new ImageView(getactivity());

Comment: and this won't work.. cz generally whatever you want to add to the layout should be within onCreateView, so if you call this async your view will be already displayed and i think you won't be able to change UI this after that.. i am not sure though..

Comment: so you should add imageview in your design only and then just show the image whichever you are getting from the server directly instead of adding it everytime

Comment: and for that using findviewbyid take imageview at class level and then onPostExecute call a method which sets your image and data.. getting??

Comment: why this is not working, use this and then send me screenshot what compiler is complaining about.. cz it is not fragment it is activity so this should work.

Comment: But the imageview you're talking in design is in another activity ?

Comment: I'm writing this in onPostExecute

Comment: Ohh if it is in diff activity how this will work? post whole code of your activities and your xmls then i will be able to help.. and you should reframe your question cz you are trying something more then what you have written so nobody else would be able to help you..

Comment: Mate it's impossible to add so much code, can I contact you personally ?

Comment: and where are you displaying linearkata layout??

Comment: and here this won't work, context is used. ImageView ivMyImage= new ImageView(context);

Comment: public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View v= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null); inflates info_window

Comment: I'm using it as content of the infowindow of every marker

Comment: i have not used googleMaps before, but i think this code of adding and displaying image comes under getInfoContents() method. cz that's where your layout has been mentioned.

Comment: I can add whichever image there yes. Problem then would be how to add the correct image for every marker.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know what maker is.. You can keep that temporary or something.. but you have to do this within getInfoContents() only.. change your question.. i think other ppl would be able to share there knowledge on this..

Comment: Alright mate, thank you anyhow I know understand why I can't do it in onPost. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889668/android-google-maps-snippet-auto-update-in-infowindow this might help you.. and don't be sorry.. I'll learn googleMaps bcs of you.. ;-)

Comment: I can reframe question for you.. might get extra help

Comment: Any help is gladly appreciated, I'm looking at the link rn.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45038059/maps-getinfocontents-tracing-through-list-but-no-assigning-correctly